# How I can find variable: Name in react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm trying to pass the 'data' to other archive (CampaignList.js > Campaign.js) but I don't now why the variable is not pass to Campaign.js function. I watched some videos on YouTube and read some forums and nothing help.

**CampaignList.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList
} from 'react-native';
import Campaign from './Campaign';

var deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
var deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.screen}>
        <FlatList
          style={styles.scroll}
          contentContainerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 20 }}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
          data={[
            {
              id: 1,
              name: 'Peregrino da Alvorada'
            }
          ]}
          keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Campaign data={item} />}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>ADICIONAR CAMPANHA</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  scroll: {
    marginHorizontal: deviceWidth * 0.05,
    marginVertical: deviceHeight * 0.025,
    height: deviceHeight * 0.6,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'black'
  },
  button: {
    marginHorizontal: deviceWidth * 0.05,
    marginVertical: deviceHeight * 0.025,
    width: deviceWidth * 0.9,
    height: deviceHeight * 0.1,
    backgroundColor: '#6a0301',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  text: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  }
});

export default App;
```

My idea is pass the data to here to create a query with RealmDB but the MetroServer returt an error "Can't find variable: Name" in the Campaign.js:

**Campaign.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default function Campaign({ data }) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Name>{data.name}</Name>
      <Id>{data.id}</Id>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  name: {
    fontSize: 50,
    color: 'black'
  },
  id: {
    fontSize: 10,
    color: 'grey'
  }
});
```

Comment: You're using components `Name` and `Id` but they're not defined or imported anywhere. Did you mean to use plain `Text` component on rendering props?

Comment: I want to rendering props. I'm new on RN.

Comment: On second thought, I want to show the information in text, I don't know if there is a difference in rederizing props I'm so sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using Text for displaying your text components, or else you can create two different components named Name and Id ( not at all required in this use case) to display the items

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet,Text} from 'react-native';

export default function Campaign({ data }) {
  return( 
    <View> 
      <Text>{data.name}</Text> 
      <Text>{data.id}</Text> 
    </View> 
  ); 
} 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
  name: { fontSize: 50, color: 'black' }, 
  id: { fontSize: 10, color: 'grey' },
});
```

In the original question, you were trying to use undefined components `Name` and `Id`.

Comment: retuned "Can't find variable: Text" :(. But thx

Comment: Please import it from 'react-native' as seen in my code.